# Percentage of the positive and negative value calculate for different zone using ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator

I have a raster data, which value range is -15 to + 20. I want to calculate the zone wise (I have one shapefile which associated with different Zones) percentage of the positive and negative value of raster for each zones using ArcGIS.

How to calculate it using ArcGIS Desktop?

Comment: Don't forget to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  I recommend not thinking about GIS SE as being some sort of online GIS tutor.  For your questions to be answered here they should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.

Comment: @PolyGeo, i am not thinking that it is any tutorial. i have no idea how to do it.

Comment: Con(A>0,zone,-zone)

Comment: @PolyGeo I disagree. For me, this questions has a straightforward answer since there is an ArcGIS tool just for that. I believe if OP doesn't know where to start, asking this question si much better than wasting time going down the wrong path and ending up with an XY problem.

Comment: @Janina There's always that risk, but my concern was whether the asker had tried anything (e.g. checking the documentation and testing a tool or two) before passing it over to our volunteers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could use [Tabulate Area](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/tabulate-area.htm). Using this tool you can calculate the area of each represented value (from the raster) within each zone, aggregate the output to negative and positive and calculate percentages.